# An explicit construction of reals added after some forcing notions

Tags: set-theory, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

Consider the forcing notion(s) introduced by Friedman (or Mitchell or Neeman) for adding a club subset of $\omega_2$ by finite conditions. In the generic extension CH fails, but I can't see the reals added by the forcing. Would you please give an explicit construction of $\aleph_2$-many reals in the generic extension by these forcings. Can we determine if  the added reals are Cohen, Random, or ....

**Remark.** The question applies to many similar forcing constructions, in particular to the forcings introduced in Neeman's paper.

**References.**

1) Friedman, Forcing with finite conditions. Set theory, 285–295, Trends Math., Birkhäuser, Basel, 2006.

2) Mitchell,  Adding closed unbounded subsets of $\omega_2$ with finite forcing. Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 46 (2005), no. 3, 357–371.

3) Neeman, Forcing with sequences of models of two types.

Comment: According to your remark this is a really interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each of the posets you mention adds $\omega_2$ many Cohen reals.  Let $G$ be generic for any of the 3 posets you mentioned.  The point is that any collection of $\omega_1$-many reals in $V[G]$ can be captured by an intermediate extension of the form $V[G \cap M]$ where $M$ is a sufficiently elementary substructure of $V$ containing $\omega_1$ as a subset and $G$ contains a strong master condition (in the sense of Mitchell) for the model $M$.  Then one can show that the quotient forcing $\mathbb{P}/(G \cap M)$ is strongly proper with respect to all countable models of the form $N[G \cap M]$, where $N$ is a countable model from $V$.  This is a general phenomenon, but in the case of these forcings it can be shown rather directly; Neeman's preprint gives the details.  The fact that the quotient is strongly proper with respect to stationarily many countable models abstractly implies that the quotient adds lots of Cohen reals; Mitchell discusses this in his paper "On the Hamkins Approximation Property".